# Configure Kendo UI to ignore device

Tags: configuration, kendo-mobile

I'm new to Kendo and have been brought on to a project using it for some of it's components.  The project is a web app (not an web app wrapper -- will be accessed via phone's web browser).  It seems it's rendering various elements differently based on the device platform/version.  Is there a way to disable it and use a global style (design dictates it looks the same on all devices)?  Sorry if it's a basic question, but haven't seen any options like this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these documentation articles:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/introduction#force-platform-rendering

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/application#forcing-platform-styles

You can also force the Flat skin:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/application#configuration-skin